# Installing DocumentDb.Emulator

Tags: windows-7, installation, azure, emulator

I can install the DocumentDb.Emulator with no errors. However, when I try to launch it I get the following error:

"The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll is missing"

I am running Windows 7. Does the emulator require a later version of Windows? I cannot see any system requirements on Microsoft's web site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [DocumentDB Emulator system requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator#documentdb-emulator-system-requirements):

> The DocumentDB Emulator has the following hardware and software
>   requirements:
>
> - Software requirements
>
>   - Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016, or **Windows 10**
> - Minimum Hardware requirements
>
>   - 2 GB RAM
>   - 10 GB available hard disk space

So there are probably some missing dependencies.

---

There is a feedback page that asks for [support for previous versions of Windows](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/17825839-add-emulator-support-for-windows-7-8), stating:

> The installer shouldn't run on unsupported platforms. Right now it goes ahead and installs and then the emulator fails with an obscure error about api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll

And a reply

> Thanks for the feedback and we will consider that. Our backend code uses some crypto APIs that are not available on Windows 7 hence it's not supported currently.